# How to call parent function value in child function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In the below code I want to use `$id` in the `whereRaw` query, but I get an error like "undefined variable".

```
public function getPendingArtistLink($id ,Request $request)
{
    if (!Auth::guard('admin')->user()->hasPermissionTo('appointment-master')) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'you have no permission to acces this']);
        return "you have no permission to acces this";
    }

    $objSalon = Artist::whereNotExists(function($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('*'))
                ->from('artist_services')
                ->whereRaw('(artists.id = artist_services.artist_id))')
                ->whereRaw('(artists.branch_id = '.$id.' AND artists.status != "Deleted"');
        })
        ->toSql();
        //->get();
    dd($objSalon);
    return view('Backend.branch.missing_artist_salon', compact('objSalon'));
}
```

How can I access my `$id` argument where I am trying?

Comment: This code is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Never concatenate variables into an SQL string, always use parametrised queries. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Why are you using RAW SQL when you can use relationships ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$objSalon = Artist::whereNotExists(function($query) use ($id) { ... })
```

but as mentioned by @Skrrp ,is better to not use that way.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use inline functions like this:

```php
    $objSalon = Artist::whereNotExists(fn($query) => 
            $query->select(DB::raw('*'))
                ->from('artist_services')
                ->whereRaw('(artists.id = artist_services.artist_id))')
                ->whereRaw('(artists.branch_id = '.$id.' AND artists.status !="Deleted"')
            )->toSql();
```

inline functions have access to variables that defined in upper scope